# SilverStripe - JavaScript variable not successfully being sent via AJAX to Page.php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, silverstripe

I'm trying to send a JavaScript variable in a template to a function called 'getMemberships' in `Page.php` but am having a lot of trouble trying to get it to work.

I know that the JavaScript function `ssCallBack` does work and gets the user information from SharpSpring. And I know the `getMemberships` functions works if you hardcode an email here:

```
$lists = $this->sharpSpringService->makeCall('getListMemberships', [
   'emailAddress' => 'youremail@site.com',
 ]);
```

I know that you can submit JavaScript data to PHP using AJAX, which I have set up and tried using various settings (tried dataType: 'json', dataType: 'jsonP', dataType: 'html') but, in `getMemberships`, `$this->getRequest()->postVars('contactemail')` is always an empty array (`$contactEmail = {array}[0]`). I can't figure out why this happens.

In the Page.ss file:

```
  function ssCallBack(resp) {  
     if (typeof resp.contact != 'undefined') {
                //this contact exists in SharpSpring
                console.log(resp.contact['Email']);
                var isSubscribed = false;
                var contactEmail = resp.contact['Email'];
                console.log(contactEmail);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/home/getMemberships",
                    data: {
                        contactemail:contactEmail
                    }
                }).done(function (response) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        console.log(response[i].status);
                        var status = response[i].status;
                        var list = response[i].list;
                        if (status == "true") {
                            if(list =="PositionistView"){
                                isSubscribedToPV = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

in `Page.php`

```
public function getMemberships(){
    $pvListID = [REDACTED];
    $listName = "[REDACTED]";
    $inPVList = false;
    $contactEmail = $this->getRequest()->postVars('contactemail');
    $converted_result ="";
    $pvSubscription = null;
    $return = [];
    $sharpSpringService = null;
    $this->sharpSpringService = new SharpSpringService("[REDACTED", "[REDACTED");

    if($contactEmail != null && $contactEmail !=""){
        $lists = $this->sharpSpringService->makeCall('getListMemberships', [
            'emailAddress' => $contactEmail,
        ]);


        if (count($lists) > 0) {
            $listArray = json_decode(json_encode($lists), true);

            foreach($listArray as $list){

                if($list = $pvListID){
                    //the user is subscribed
                    $inPVList = true;
                    $converted_result = ($inPVList) ? 'true' : 'false';
                }
            }
        }
        $return[] = array(
            "status" => $converted_result,
            "list" => $listName
        );
        return json_encode($return);
    }
    return $return;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `postVar('contactemail')`. `postVars()` returns all post variables.

Comment: Using postVar() does not work either. It just returns a null value, which is not correct.

Comment: I figured out the issue. The email I was testing with wasn't actually part of the subscription list I was referencing in my getMemberships code, and, long story short, that was mucking everything up.